# Is ssh -g redundant with 0.0.0.0?

Tags: ssh

Is there any difference between the following two commands?

```
ssh -g -L 8080:localhost:80 bob@example.com
ssh -L 8080:0.0.0.0:80 bob@example.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two unrelated values.

`openssh`'s option [`-g`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html#g) is equivalent to specifying client's `ssh_config`'s option [`-o GatewayPorts=yes`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#GatewayPorts). They affect the unwritten optional part that can be prepended on the [`-L`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html#L) option:

> `-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`

Without `-g` (and `GatewayPorts` defaulting to `no`)  nor specifying any local bind, ssh binds by default to *localhost* (which in turns means IPv4 `127.0.0.1`+ IPv6 `::1`). With `-g` (or with `-o GatewayPorts=yes`) it binds by default to INADDR_ANY (`0.0.0.0`) + in6addr_any (`::`). Whatever the default or options present, the local address can instead be overridden on the client by prepending what IP address to bind to in the `-L` option.

So:

```
ssh -g -L 8080:localhost:80 bob@example.com
```

is equivalent to:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:8080:localhost:80 bob@example.com
```

or on IPv6 enabled systems if wanting both protocols:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:8080:localhost:80 -L '[::]:8080:localhost:80' bob@example.com
```

Now, unrelated to `-g`, OP's second command:

> ```
> ssh -L 8080:0.0.0.0:80 bob@example.com
> ```

is usually a plain mistake: it tells the remote end to *connect* to, not *bind* to, INADDR_ANY.

For a *destination* that means: don't choose the destination, let the system decide when connecting the socket. In such case, the remote system (as asked by the remote `sshd` server) chooses one of its own addresses and might choose 127.0.0.1 or $HOST or we don't know (on my remote system test, it chose 127.0.0.1).

> ```
> connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16)
> ```

with an actual connection made (on my test) from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: So I understand the -g vs GatewayPorts equivalence. You lost me here: `ssh -g -L 8080:localhost:80 bob@example.com` ==  `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:localhost:80 bob@example.com` Aren't you missing an :8080?

Comment: @fny typo I'll fix it

Comment: Doesn't -g depends on GatewayPorts=yes|clientspecified being set in sshd_config?  "it tells the remote end to connect to not bind to INADDR_ANY." I Isn't sshd_config is what makes the determination?

Comment: for the 2nd part: it's not the place. server's GatewayPorts affects -R not -L, and affects binds (just as client's GatewayPorts), not connects